# React router loop and return

Tags: reactjs, loops, routes

I am trying to return my routes from an array using loop. I have an app.js file where my code is like this:

```
  return (          
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={() => <HomePage />} exact />
        <Route path="/chooseStyles" component={FormContainer} />
        <Route path="/heightAndWeight" component={FormContainer} />
        <Route path="/bodyShape" component={FormContainer} />
        </Switch>
);
```

I am trying to make my routes dynamic and loop through an array. But I am unable to make it work. For that, I am trying this code:

```
return (          
      <Switch>
         {a.map((b,i) => <Route path={b[i].url} component={() => <Global_Container name={a[0].path} />}  />)}
        <Route path="/" component={() => <HomePage />} exact />
        <Route path="/chooseStyles" component={FormContainer} />
        <Route path="/heightAndWeight" component={FormContainer} />
        <Route path="/bodyShape" component={FormContainer} />
        </Switch>
);
```

Using code above I am getting errors. I have created a variable called a like this:

```
var a = [{"url":"/global","path":"maternityFit"},
            {"url":"/global1","path":"clothFit"}
        ]
```

My code works fine when I am using code like this:

```
  {a.map((b,i) => <Route path={a[0].url} component={() => <Global_Container name={a[0].path} />}  />)}
```

I don't know how to make it work in my case. I am declaring my var a in code block:

```
export default function App() {
  var a = [{"url":"/global","path":"maternityFit"},
            {"url":"/global1","path":"clothFit"}
        ]
}
```

Comment: Can you include the error message you're getting?

Comment: Without knowing the error I can't give an answer, but I can point out that in the breaking example you are still using the `0` index for the `name` prop.

Comment: @HenryWoody it was unable to detect url

Comment: What is "it"? Can you update the question to include the text of the error message?

Comment: {"url":"/global","path":"maternityFit"}, b[i].url is unable to detect url any way when I removed b[i].url to b.url it is working. But I am unable to understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` function isn't being used correctly. `b` has the current value of the array, You shouldn't be doing `b.[index]`. `b` is already the result of doing `a[index]`; just use it instead. [Documentation on `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Instead you should be doing this:

```js
{a.map((b) => (
  <Route path={b.url} component={() => <Global_Container name={b.path} />}  />
  //           ^ b is the object not array                     ^ Use b here instead of a
))}
```

To further visualize what is happening consider the following:

```js
var myArray = [{ val1: 'foo' }, { val1: 'bar' }]

myArray.map((obj, index) => {
  console.log('myArray: ', myArray); // Still the full array
  console.log('obj: ', obj); // The current value in the loop
  console.log('index: ', index); // The current index in the loop
});
```

So the issue was you were tying to use `obj` as if it were `myArray`. But instead you can skip the extra characters of typing out `myArray[index]` and just use `obj`.